# Best framework to integrate with Compose Tests for a Native Android App?

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-jetpack-compose, android-espresso, gui-testing

I'm planning to create a framework on Compose Test for Native android app, what's the best framework architecture i can use? The framework should be robust enough to handle all the aspects of Test Automation

I was thinking about POM, but suggestions are welcome.

Comment: This is an opinion-based question that will have lots of subjective answers. Try posting on the wiki instead, or try a framework yourself and ask specific questions about it.